# What is best practice for passing files and directories as command line arguments to a containerized program?

Tags: docker, containers

I am working to containerize a program. The program requires a configuration file and directories for its operation, which are passed as command line arguments, e.g. something like this:

```sh
$ myprog -c /path/to/config.conf -i /directory/with/input_files -o /directory/with/output_files
```

I know that I will need mount docker volumes to the containerized version of this program  so that it can access the config file and directories. But, I would like to maintain the command-line interface unchanged (as far as possible) to hide the complexity of using docker volumes, etc. from users. How do I do this?

Will I need to create a wrapper script that maps the values of the command-line arguments (`-c`, `-i`, `-o`) to mount the corresponding paths as docker volumes? If so, what is the best practice for packaging it (i.e. to distribute the script with the container) and making this work cross-platform (i.e. so that it runs on Windows, MacOS, Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228877/19238131) for the files within your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
    - ./config:/path/to
    - ./input:/directory/with/input_files
    - ./output:/directory/with/output_files
```

*Do note* that I mount the entire folder in this example, despite you only mentioning one config file. This is on purpose - reasons for that are well explained within [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXfL0UCO9F4). Resources on how to define `docker-compose.yml` in full can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). Your final approach could look something like this:

1. Push Dockerfile to registry of your choice
2. Provide user the `docker-compose.yml` for example via Git
3. User creates folder with the necessary sub-directories (`config`, `input` and `output` in this example)
4. User supplies valid config file in `config` folder
5. User executes `docker-compose up -d`
6. Success :)